# repeatedly solving the same large sparse SPD system of equations

Tags: matlab, matrix, linear-algebra

I've got a large sparse system of linear equations. It is represented by an equally large sparse, symmetric, positive-definite matrix `A` (that comes from the discretization of a differential operator). I need to solve a system `Ax = b` many times (time stepping) in a row, where the matrix `A` never changes, but `x` and `b` do.

What is the most efficient way to do so?

So far I used Matlab's built-in `L= chol(A,'lower');` to calculate a Cholesky decomposition `A == L*L` *once* in the beginning and solve the system in each step as `x = L'\(L\b);`